# Leer un archivo de largo variable con SpringBatch

Tags: java, spring, batch

Estoy tratando de leer un archivo de la siguiente forma:

```
@Bean
public ItemReader<TxIssuerUtil> readerIssuer() {

    FlatFileItemReader<TxIssuerUtil> reader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource("Text.txt"));
    //reader.setLinesToSkip(0);
    reader.setMaxItemCount(1000000);
    reader.setLineMapper(productLineMapperIssuer());
    return  reader;
}

@Bean
public LineMapper<TxIssuerUtil> productLineMapperIssuer(){
    DefaultLineMapper<TxIssuerUtil> mapper = new DefaultLineMapper<TxIssuerUtil>();
    mapper.setLineTokenizer(productLineTokenizer());
    mapper.setFieldSetMapper((fieldSet) -> validateItemReaderIssuer(fieldSet));
    return mapper;

}
```

Y estoy dando el rango que necesito para el mapeo de campos.

```
public LineTokenizer productLineTokenizer() {
    FixedLengthTokenizer tokenizer = new FixedLengthTokenizer();
    tokenizer.setColumns(new Range[] {new Range(1,10),new Range(11,11),new Range(12,19),new Range(20,38),new Range(39,41),
                         new Range(42,60),new Range(61,63 ),new Range(64,65),new Range(66,76),new Range(77,77),new Range(78,84),
                         new Range(85,87),new Range(88,90),new Range(91,98), new Range(99,101), new Range(102,102 )});
    tokenizer.setNames(new String[] {"filler1","activeInactiveCode","accountRangeLow","gcmsProductId","filler4","accountRangeHigh","filler5",
            "cardProgramIdentifier","filler6","memberId","productTypeId","endPoint","countryCodeAlpha","countryCodeNumeric",
            "filelr11","licensedProductId","filler12"});
    return tokenizer;
}
```

El problema esta, en que no necesito leer el largo completo del archivo, solo necesito hasta la posicion que le doy.

El archivo no tiene un largo fijo, puede variar de la siguiente forma:

```
Linea1:texto
linea2:texto de prueba
linea3:otro texto de prueba
linea4:texto nuevamente
```

Entonces cuando ya le doy el valor maximo que necesito, que sera en donde obtendre el valor requerido.

`new Range(102,102 )` me devuelve el siguiente error al ejecutar:

```
 Line is shorter than max range 102
```

El tema es que el archivo nunca tendra un largo maximo fijo, puede variar, pero solo necesito una parte de este archivo (en donde le doy el rango). Alguna idea?

Comment: Segun entiendo el archivo no tiene un largo predeterminado, pero la cantidad de columnas es siempre la misma, correcto? No es posible usar algun tipo de caracter para determinar el inicio y fin de cada columna, con un caracter como la coma o tab, como en los archivos CSV?

Comment: hola, no, el archivo no tiene una cabecera, cantidad predeterminada de columnas, ni delimitadores

Comment: En ese caso tendrias que implementar tu propio tokenizador (extendiendo [LineTokenizer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/LineTokenizer.html)) que verifique el largo de la cadena de texto antes de tratar de extraer el valor para la columna.